# Why doesnt hibernate give up trying to get connection

Tags: java, hibernate, c3p0

My java code I had some tasks running on an ExecutorService that was hanging I interrupted them after 30 minutes. They were all hanging on trying to quire a database connection, I dont actually think this was because there were no connections left because these were the first tasks trying to write data to the database. But regardless my question is why didnt they give up trying to aquire a connection long before the 30 minutes up because **hibernate.c3p0.acquireRetryAttempts** was set to 10, and the default gap between retrys is just one second.

**Stack Trace**

```
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:304)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:169)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:67)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:160)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1392)
at com.jthink.songlayer.hibernate.HibernateUtil.beginTransaction(HibernateUtil.java:145)
at com.jthink.songkong.analyse.acoustid.AcoustId.addToDatabase(AcoustId.java:1052)
at com.jthink.songkong.analyse.acoustid.AcoustId.getListOfRecordingTitlesForAcoustIds(AcoustId.java:1218)
at com.jthink.songkong.analyse.musicbrainz.scoring.MusicBrainzScorer.calculateReleaseScore2(MusicBrainzScorer.java:342)
at com.jthink.songkong.analyse.musicbrainz.scoring.MusicBrainzScorer.calculateReleaseScores(MusicBrainzScorer.java:524)
at com.jthink.songkong.analyse.musicbrainz.scoring.MusicBrainzScorer.calculateBestReleaseScore(MusicBrainzScorer.java:222)
at com.jthink.songkong.analyse.analyser.AbstractMusicBrainzGroupMatcher.scoreAndUpdateWithBestMatch(AbstractMusicBrainzGroupMatcher.java:144)
at com.jthink.songkong.analyse.analyser.AbstractMusicBrainzGroupMatcher.matchSongsToRelease(AbstractMusicBrainzGroupMatcher.java:122)
at com.jthink.songkong.analyse.analyser.AbstractMusicBrainzGroupMatcher.matchSongs(AbstractMusicBrainzGroupMatcher.java:69)
at com.jthink.songkong.analyse.analyser.MusicBrainzSongGroupMatcher.call(MusicBrainzSongGroupMatcher.java:236)
at com.jthink.songkong.analyse.analyser.MusicBrainzSongGroupMatcher1.call(MusicBrainzSongGroupMatcher1.java:69)
at com.jthink.songkong.analyse.analyser.MusicBrainzSongGroupMatcher1.call(MusicBrainzSongGroupMatcher1.java:12)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**Hibernate Configuration**

```
 Configuration config = new Configuration();

        config.setProperty(Environment.DRIVER,"org.h2.Driver");
        config.setProperty(Environment.URL,"jdbc:h2:"+Db.DBFOLDER+"/"+Db.DBNAME+";FILE_LOCK=SOCKET;MVCC=TRUE;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;CACHE_SIZE=50000");
        config.setProperty(Environment.DIALECT,"org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect");
        config.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username","jaikoz");
        config.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password","jaikoz");
        config.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.numHelperThreads","10");
        config.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.min_size","20");
        config.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.max_size","100");
        config.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.timeout","300");
        config.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.maxStatementsPerConnection","50");
        config.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period","3000");
        config.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.acquireRetryAttempts","10");
```

Comment: if you are not seeing Exceptions in your logs, the issue probably isn't with acquiring Connections from the database. it's probably a Connection leak. please try setting `hibernate.c3p0.unreturnedConnectionTimeout` and `hibernate.c3p0.debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces`. See http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuring_to_debug_and_workaround_broken_clients

Comment: Okay I'll set those options, build a new version and see if that sheds any more light onto the problem.

Comment: @SteveWaldman I think the problem is that I get a connection (for a hibernate Session) then do various things, then some non db code get stuck so the connection never gets released so I eventually run out of connections. But the bug is not so much that my code is not releasing connection when it has finished but that it doesn't finish so cant release the connection. Could I use the hibernate.c3p0.unreturnedConnectionTimeout option to safetly release that connection even if the thread is stuck doing something else or not

Comment: "safely" is a judgment call unreturnedConnectionTimeout forcibly close()es a Connection checked out by a client. it isn't gentle. if there is an issue in your application's code that prevents Connections from being released, the best thing to do is to understand and resolve that issue. but, if that is not possible — if for example the problem is in library code you cannot modify — then, absolutely, unreturnedConnectionTimeout can be used to work around that.

Comment: if you decide that the best you can do is workaround with unreturnedConnectionTimeout, 1) turn off debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces — it imposes a performance penalty and you have already understood the problem; 2) it's an art to get the timeout right. it should be long enough that genuinely in-use Connections never get expired, but not so long that the pool is exhausted while waiting for stranded Connections to expire.